# webscraping stars from imdb page using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the name of stars from an IMDb page. below is my code

```
from requests import get
    url = 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=tv_movie,tv_series&user_rating=6.0,10.0&adult=include&ref_=adv_prv'
    response = get(url)
   
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
movie_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', 'lister-item mode-advanced')
first_movie = movie_containers[0]

first_stars = first_movie.select('a[href*="name"]')
first_stars
```

I got the following output

```
[<a href="/name/nm0644022/">Bob Odenkirk</a>,
 <a href="/name/nm0781533/">Rhea Seehorn</a>,
 <a href="/name/nm0052186/">Jonathan Banks</a>,
 <a href="/name/nm3103126/">Michael Mando</a>]
```

i am trying to get only the names of the stars and `first_stars.text` gives the following error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3104\1297903165.py in <module>
      1 first_stars = first_movie.select('a[href*="name"]')
----> 2 first_stars.text

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py in __getattr__(self, key)
   2288         """Raise a helpful exception to explain a common code fix."""
   2289         raise AttributeError(
-> 2290             "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
   2291         )

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

when i tried

```
first_stars = first_movie.find('a[href*="name"]')
first_stars.text
```

i also got the following error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3104\2359725208.py in <module>
      1 first_stars = first_movie.find('a[href*="name"]')
----> 2 first_stars.text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Any idea how i can extract only the name of the stars?

Answer (score 2):

If you need the star name without distinction this might help.

```
block = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"lister-item mode-advanced"})

starList= list()
for star in block:
    starList.append(star.find("p", attrs={"class":""}).text.replace("Stars:", "").replace("\n", "").strip())

print(starList)
```

It prints

```
['Bob Odenkirk, Rhea Seehorn, Jonathan Banks, Michael Mando', 'Jason Bateman, Laura Linney, Sofia Hublitz, Skylar Gaertner', 'Gia Sandhu, Anson Mount, Ethan Peck, Jess Bush', 'Josh Brolin, Imogen Poots, Lili Taylor, Tom Pelphrey', 'Pablo Schreiber, Shabana Azmi, Natasha Culzac, Olive Gray', 'Titus Welliver, Mimi Rogers, Madison Lintz, Stephen A. Chang', 'Rachel Griffiths, Sophia Ali, Shannon Berry, Jenna Clause', 'Adam Scott, Zach Cherry, Britt Lower, Tramell Tillman', 'Milo Ventimiglia, Mandy Moore, Sterling K. Brown, Chrissy Metz', 'Emilia Clarke, Peter Dinklage, Kit Harington, Lena Headey', 'Bryan Cranston, Aaron Paul, Anna Gunn, Betsy Brandt', 'Millie Bobby Brown, Finn Wolfhard, Winona Ryder, David Harbour', 'Joe Locke, Kit Connor, Yasmin Finney, William Gao', 'John C. Reilly, Quincy Isaiah, Jason Clarke, Gaby Hoffmann', 'Bill Hader, Stephen Root, Sarah Goldberg, Anthony Carrigan', 'Kaley Cuoco, Zosia Mamet, Griffin Matthews, Rosie Perez', 'Caitríona Balfe, Sam Heughan, Sophie Skelton, Richard Rankin', 'Evan Rachel Wood, Jeffrey Wright, Ed Harris, Thandiwe Newton', 'Patrick Stewart, Alison Pill, Michelle Hurd, Santiago Cabrera', 'Nicola Coughlan, Jonathan Bailey, Ruth Gemmell, Florence Hunt', 'Andrew Lincoln, Norman Reedus, Melissa McBride, Lauren Cohan', 'Cillian Murphy, Paul Anderson, Sophie Rundle, Helen McCrory', 'Manuel Garcia-Rulfo, Becki Newton, Neve Campbell, Christopher Gorham', 'Jane Fonda, Lily Tomlin, Sam Waterston, Martin Sheen', 'Ellen Pompeo, Chandra Wilson, James Pickens Jr., Justin Chambers', 'Alexander Dreymon, Eliza Butterworth, Arnas Fedaravicius, Mark Rowley', 'Luke Grimes, Kelly Reilly, Wes Bentley, Cole Hauser', 'Elisabeth Moss, Wagner Moura, Phillipa Soo, Chris Chalk', "Scott Whyte, Nolan North, Steven Pacey, Emily O'Brien", 'Steve Carell, Jenna Fischer, John Krasinski, Rainn Wilson', 'Jodie Whittaker, Peter Capaldi, Pearl Mackie, Matt Smith', 'Ansel 
Elgort, Ken Watanabe, Rachel Keller, Shô Kasamatsu', 'James Spader, Megan Boone, Diego Klattenhoff, Ryan Eggold', 'Mark Harmon, David McCallum, Sean Murray, Pauley Perrette', 'Zendaya, Hunter Schafer, Angus Cloud, Jacob Elordi', 'Niv Sultan, Shaun Toub, Shervin Alenabi, Arash Marandi', 'Asa Butterfield, Gillian Anderson, Emma Mackey, Ncuti Gatwa', 'Jack Lowden, Kristin Scott Thomas, Gary Oldman, Chris Reilly', 'Karl Urban, Jack Quaid, Antony Starr, Erin Moriarty', 'Mariska Hargitay, Christopher Meloni, Ice-T, Dann Florek', "Nathan Fillion, Alyssa Diaz, Richard T. Jones, Melissa O'Neil", "Saoirse-Monica Jackson, Louisa Harland, Tara Lynne O'Neill, Kathy Kiera Clarke", 'Donald Glover, Brian Tyree Henry, LaKeith Stanfield, Zazie Beetz', 'Jennifer Aniston, Courteney Cox, Lisa Kudrow, Matt LeBlanc', 'Jared Padalecki, Jensen Ackles, Jim Beaver, Misha Collins', 'Julia Roberts, Sean Penn, Dan Stevens, Betty Gilpin', 'James Gandolfini, Lorraine Bracco, Edie Falco, Michael Imperioli', 'Natasha Lyonne, Charlie Barnett, Greta Lee, Elizabeth Ashley', 'Jean Smart, Hannah Einbinder, Carl Clemons-Hopkins, Rose Abdoo', 'Katheryn Winnick, Gustaf Skarsgård, Alexander Ludwig, Georgia Hirst']
```

or if you need both title and its stars

```
block = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"lister-item mode-advanced"})

starList= list()
movieDict = dict()
for star in block:
    movieDict = {
        "moviename":star.find("h3", attrs={"class":"lister-item-header"}).text.split("\n")[2], 
        "stars": star.find("p", attrs={"class":""}).text.replace("Stars:", "").replace("\n", "").strip()
    }
    starList.append(movieDict)
print(starList)
```

this will print

```
[{'moviename': 'Better Call Saul', 'stars': 'Bob Odenkirk, Rhea Seehorn, Jonathan Banks, Michael 
Mando'}, {'moviename': 'Ozark', 'stars': 'Jason Bateman, Laura Linney, Sofia Hublitz, Skylar Gaertner'}, {'moviename': 'Star Trek: Strange New Worlds', 'stars': 'Gia Sandhu, Anson Mount, Ethan Peck, Jess Bush'}, {'moviename': 'Outer Range', 'stars': 'Josh Brolin, Imogen Poots, Lili Taylor, 
Tom Pelphrey'}, {'moviename': 'Halo', 'stars': 'Pablo Schreiber, Shabana Azmi, Natasha Culzac, Olive Gray'}, {'moviename': 'Bosch: Legacy', 'stars': 'Titus Welliver, Mimi Rogers, Madison Lintz, 
Stephen A. Chang'}, {'moviename': 'The Wilds', 'stars': 'Rachel Griffiths, Sophia Ali, Shannon Berry, Jenna Clause'}, {'moviename': 'Severance', 'stars': 'Adam Scott, Zach Cherry, Britt Lower, Tramell Tillman'}, {'moviename': 'This Is Us', 'stars': 'Milo Ventimiglia, Mandy Moore, Sterling K. Brown, Chrissy Metz'}, {'moviename': 'Game of Thrones', 'stars': 'Emilia Clarke, Peter Dinklage, Kit Harington, Lena Headey'}, {'moviename': 'Breaking Bad', 'stars': 'Bryan Cranston, Aaron Paul, Anna Gunn, Betsy Brandt'}, {'moviename': 'Stranger Things', 'stars': 'Millie Bobby Brown, Finn Wolfhard, Winona Ryder, David Harbour'}, {'moviename': 'Heartstopper', 'stars': 'Joe Locke, Kit 
Connor, Yasmin Finney, William Gao'}, {'moviename': 'Winning Time: The Rise of the Lakers Dynasty', 'stars': 'John C. Reilly, Quincy Isaiah, Jason Clarke, Gaby Hoffmann'}, {'moviename': 'Barry', 'stars': 'Bill Hader, Stephen Root, Sarah Goldberg, Anthony Carrigan'}, {'moviename': 'The Flight Attendant', 'stars': 'Kaley Cuoco, Zosia Mamet, Griffin Matthews, Rosie Perez'}, {'moviename': 
'Outlander', 'stars': 'Caitríona Balfe, Sam Heughan, Sophie Skelton, Richard Rankin'}, {'moviename': 'Westworld', 'stars': 'Evan Rachel Wood, Jeffrey Wright, Ed Harris, Thandiwe Newton'}, {'moviename': 'Star Trek: Picard', 'stars': 'Patrick Stewart, Alison Pill, Michelle Hurd, Santiago Cabrera'}, {'moviename': 'Bridgerton', 'stars': 'Nicola Coughlan, Jonathan Bailey, Ruth Gemmell, Florence Hunt'}, {'moviename': 'The Walking Dead', 'stars': 'Andrew Lincoln, Norman Reedus, Melissa McBride, Lauren Cohan'}, {'moviename': 'Peaky Blinders', 'stars': 'Cillian Murphy, Paul Anderson, 
Sophie Rundle, Helen McCrory'}, {'moviename': 'The Lincoln Lawyer', 'stars': 'Manuel Garcia-Rulfo, Becki Newton, Neve Campbell, Christopher Gorham'}, {'moviename': 'Grace and Frankie', 'stars': 
'Jane Fonda, Lily Tomlin, Sam Waterston, Martin Sheen'}, {'moviename': "Grey's Anatomy", 'stars': 'Ellen Pompeo, Chandra Wilson, James Pickens Jr., Justin Chambers'}, {'moviename': 'The Last Kingdom', 'stars': 'Alexander Dreymon, Eliza Butterworth, Arnas Fedaravicius, Mark Rowley'}, {'moviename': 'Yellowstone', 'stars': 'Luke Grimes, Kelly Reilly, Wes Bentley, Cole Hauser'}, {'moviename': 'Shining Girls', 'stars': 'Elisabeth Moss, Wagner Moura, Phillipa Soo, Chris Chalk'}, {'moviename': 'Love, Death & Robots', 'stars': "Scott Whyte, Nolan North, Steven Pacey, Emily O'Brien"}, {'moviename': 'The Office', 'stars': 'Steve Carell, Jenna Fischer, John Krasinski, Rainn Wilson'}, {'moviename': 'Doctor Who', 'stars': 'Jodie Whittaker, Peter Capaldi, Pearl Mackie, Matt Smith'}, {'moviename': 'Tokyo Vice', 'stars': 'Ansel Elgort, Ken Watanabe, Rachel Keller, Shô Kasamatsu'}, {'moviename': 'The Blacklist', 'stars': 'James Spader, Megan Boone, Diego Klattenhoff, Ryan 
Eggold'}, {'moviename': 'NCIS: Naval Criminal Investigative Service', 'stars': 'Mark Harmon, David McCallum, Sean Murray, Pauley Perrette'}, {'moviename': 'Euphoria', 'stars': 'Zendaya, Hunter Schafer, Angus Cloud, Jacob Elordi'}, {'moviename': 'Tehran', 'stars': 'Niv Sultan, Shaun Toub, Shervin Alenabi, Arash Marandi'}, {'moviename': 'Sex Education', 'stars': 'Asa Butterfield, Gillian Anderson, Emma Mackey, Ncuti Gatwa'}, {'moviename': 'Slow Horses', 'stars': 'Jack Lowden, Kristin Scott Thomas, Gary Oldman, Chris Reilly'}, {'moviename': 'The Boys', 'stars': 'Karl Urban, Jack Quaid, Antony Starr, Erin Moriarty'}, {'moviename': 'Law & Order: Special Victims Unit', 'stars': 'Mariska Hargitay, Christopher Meloni, Ice-T, Dann Florek'}, {'moviename': 'The Rookie', 'stars': "Nathan Fillion, Alyssa Diaz, Richard T. Jones, Melissa O'Neil"}, {'moviename': 'Derry Girls', 'stars': "Saoirse-Monica Jackson, Louisa Harland, Tara Lynne O'Neill, Kathy Kiera Clarke"}, {'moviename': 'Atlanta', 'stars': 'Donald Glover, Brian Tyree Henry, LaKeith Stanfield, Zazie Beetz'}, {'moviename': 'Friends', 'stars': 'Jennifer Aniston, Courteney Cox, Lisa Kudrow, Matt LeBlanc'}, {'moviename': 'Supernatural', 'stars': 'Jared Padalecki, Jensen Ackles, Jim Beaver, Misha Collins'}, {'moviename': 'Gaslit', 'stars': 'Julia Roberts, Sean Penn, Dan Stevens, Betty Gilpin'}, {'moviename': 'The Sopranos', 'stars': 'James Gandolfini, Lorraine Bracco, Edie Falco, Michael Imperioli'}, {'moviename': 'Russian Doll', 'stars': 'Natasha Lyonne, Charlie Barnett, Greta Lee, Elizabeth Ashley'}, {'moviename': 'Hacks', 'stars': 'Jean Smart, Hannah Einbinder, Carl Clemons-Hopkins, Rose Abdoo'}, {'moviename': 'Vikings', 'stars': 'Katheryn Winnick, Gustaf Skarsgård, Alexander Ludwig, Georgia Hirst'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate the `ResultSet`:

```
first_stars = [s.text for s in first_movie.select('a[href*="name"]')]
first_stars
```

Output:

```
['Bob Odenkirk', 'Rhea Seehorn', 'Jonathan Banks', 'Michael Mando']
```